# Don't understand casting out nines

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

**Let n be a positive integer. If the sum of the digits of n is divisible by 9, then n is divisible by 9.**

I got upto here,

```
100a + 10b + c = n
a + b + c = 9k; k exists in the set Z (all integers)
```

I didn't know what to do after this, so I consulted the solution

The next step is:

```
100a + 10b + c = n = 9k + 99a + 9b = 9(k + 11a + b):
```

I don't get how you can add `99a + 9b` randomly, can someone please explain this for me

Comment: Ok, but I dont know how to delete this

Answer (score 5):

$100a+10b+c=(99a+a)+(9b+b)+c=(99a+9b)+(a+b+c)=9(11a+b)+9k=9(11a+b+k)$.

*Addendum*. Two points.

1. First, this isn't exactly what is usually referred to as ["casting out nines"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines), which is detailed on the linked Wikipedia page. This is just a method for checking that a number divides by 9.
2. Since I did it for you, you should consider trying a similar method to figure out how the sum of the digits of a number can tell you if it divides by 3. How can you tell if a number divides by 6?

Comment: About your first addendum: you cannot deny that there's a relation though. Casting out nines is a simple checksum by taking mod 9 all the summands and the sum and using the fact that $[(a \mod 9) + (b \mod 9)] \mod 9 = (a+b) \mod 9$.